# ASP.Net core Access to the path denied (obj) after publish to IIS on app startup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis, plesk

after publishing my website to a Plesk host with IIS i received this error

***An error occurred while starting the application.***

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\www\httpdocs\obj' is denied.
System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(string fullPath, byte[] securityDescriptor)
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(string path)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.SigningKeysLoader.LoadDevelopment(string path, bool createIfMissing)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory<TOptions>.Create(string name)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager<TOptions>+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
System.Lazy<T>.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
System.Lazy<T>.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, bool useDefaultConstructor)
System.Lazy<T>.CreateValue()
System.Lazy<T>.get_Value()
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache<TOptions>.GetOrAdd(string name, Func<TOptions> createOptions)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager<TOptions>.Get(string name)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager<TOptions>.get_Value()
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions+<>c.<AddClients>b__7_1(IServiceProvider sp)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.TestService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type service, ILogger logger, string message, bool doThrow)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.Validate(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityServer(IApplicationBuilder app, IdentityServerMiddlewareOptions options)
EnglishToefl.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in Startup.cs
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapExceptions)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

This is while i didn't create any folder in my app startup!!
I think this is because of Identity Server which is by default installed in my app.
ASP.net core version is 3.1 and IIS is 10.
EDIT 1:
Also Configure part of Startup.cs is

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseAuthentication();
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseIdentityServer();
      }

      app.UseAuthorization();
      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
      });

      app.UseSpa(spa =>
      {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
          spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
      });
    }
```

Thanks for your time!
App run locally without problem but after publish i receive error.

Comment: OK! Finally it's solved! it was because Environment variable Development was set in Web.config!!

Comment: Can you please be more specific in how the variable looks in the web config?